# How can you use Android Studios logcat viewer with a logfile instead of live ADB connection

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

How can I use the Android Studio logcat viewer to look at and filter a logfile of logcat logs instead of a live adb connection? Is this even possible? This would be incredibly useful, especially with the new Canary Logcat formatter.